# Looking for a Java fuzzing library or fuzzer tool with a good API

Tags: java, fuzzing

Are there any fuzzer libraries out there for Java?

I'd like to sprinkle fuzzing capabilities into existing Java web-based automated integration tests. I've done a lot of searching but I'm coming up empty for a library that supports HTTP/S. There are a lot of Python tools, but I'd like to stick with Java since that's what the programmers are using.

[JBroFuzz](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_JBroFuzz) essentially has the fuzzing capabilities I need, but I need an API and they haven't released one yet.

Answer (score 4):

A quick search turned up the [javafuzz](http://code.google.com/p/javafuzz/) library.

Comment: Thanks. That might work. I should have been more specific in the question - I'm targeting HTTP/S.

Comment: It doesn't seem to come with an API (unless you dig into the source). Only command line use (against a particular class) is documented. This limits applicability a bit, although it's nothing that can't be fixed by delving into the source. Just not so convenient.

Answer (score 2):

The people with JBroFuzz have made it possible to use it as a library:
 http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_JBroFuzz_Tutorial#How_to_Use_JBroFuzz_as_a_Fuzzing_Library